# Help with $\int{\frac{1}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int{\frac{1}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}}dx$

First, I divided by $\cos(x)$, obtaining:

$\int{\frac{\sec(x)}{\tan(x)+1}}dx$

Then using the substitution $u-1 = \tan(x)$, I got:

$\int{\frac{1}{u\sec(x)}}du$ = $\int\frac{1}{u \sqrt{(u-1)^2+1}}du$

Now I need help with moving on from here as I am stuck, thank you. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: A better change of variable may be $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$ and then use $\sin x=\frac{2 t}{1+t^2} \quad$ et $\quad \cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$. More generally, you may be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioche%27s_rules .

Comment: Hint: rewrite the original integrand as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sec(x-\frac14\pi)$ if you know how to integrate that; otherwise, @Lelouch's advice [is good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioche%27s_rules).

Comment: @Lelouch Thank you for this information, I did not know about this substitution.

Comment: This is not always the best substitution when you deal with trigonometric integrals (it can lead to a lot of computations) but it will always work in the end (if it only involves a rational function in $\cos$ and $\sin$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Use the Weierstrass substitution $u = \tan(x/2)$, which leads to $$\sin(x) = \frac{2u}{1+u^2}, \qquad \cos(x) = \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}, \qquad dx = 2 d(\arctan u) = \frac{2du}{1+u^2}. $$

**Slicker hint.** Use the *almost-Weierstrass* substitution $v+1 = \tan(x/2)$, which leads to
$$\sin(x) = \frac{2(v+1)}{1+(v+1)^2}, \qquad \cos(x)=\frac{1-(v+1)^2}{1+(v+1)^2}, \qquad  dx = \frac{2 dv}{1+(v+1)^2}, $$
then either use a trigonometric substitution or partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{\sin x+\cos x} dx\ =\ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\left( \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cos x\right)} dx\ =\ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \sin\left( x+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)} dx$
$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int \csc\left( x+\frac{\pi }{4}\right) dx\ =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \log|\tan(( x+\pi /4) /2|=\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \log|\tan( x/2+\pi /8) |\ $

Answer (score 2):

Two hints:

Hint 1 (following your track): Instead use the substitution $\tan x = \sinh t$ which gives the integrand

$$\int \frac{dt}{\sinh t + 1} = \int\frac{2\:d(e^t+1)}{(e^t+1)^2-2}$$

which integrates to an artanh.

Hint 2: $\sin x + \cos x = A\cos(x + \phi)$ which turns the integrand into something of the form

$$\int \frac{1}{A}\sec(x+\phi)\:dx$$

Solve for $A$ and $\phi$ and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

**Rationalisation**
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{1}{\sin x+\cos x} d x = & \int \frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos ^2 x-\sin ^2 x} d x \\
= & \int \frac{d(\sin x)}{1-2 \sin ^2 x}+\int \frac{d(\cos x)}{2 \cos ^2 x-1} \\
= & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}}\left[\ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{2}+2 \sin x}{\sqrt{2}-2 \sin x}\right|+\ln \left|\frac{\sqrt{2}-2 \cos x}{\sqrt{2}+2 \cos x}\right|\right]+C
\end{aligned}
$$